# jQuery show grandparent of closest element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML below (generated using CakePHP):

I am trying to show the grandparent element of a closest element that was clicked:

```
$('.what_is_the_quote_for').closest('.form-group').hide();

$('.visit_status').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '2') {
        $(this).closest('.what_is_the_quote_for').parent().parent().show();
    }
});
```

I am not sure I am using the closest() method properly here as I have read that it goes up the DOM tree whereas in this case the element I am trying to get to is below the element it starts from. Is there any way I can achieve this?

The HTML generated below is in a loop, so there will be many instances of it, therefore I cannot just access by the ID's hence the reason I am using `this.closest()`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Visit0VisitStatus" class="col-md-4 control-label">Visit Status</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="data[Visit][0][visit_status]" class="visit_status select2-hidden-accessible" id="Visit0VisitStatus" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="0">Complete</option>
            <option value="1">In Progress</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">First visit complete – quote to be submitted</option>
            <option value="3">First visit complete – parts required</option>
            <option value="4">Further visit required</option>
            <option value="5">Attended – passed back to Diamond</option>
            </select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: auto;">
            <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-Visit0VisitStatus-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-Visit0VisitStatus-container" title="First visit complete – quote to be submitted">First visit complete – quote to be submitted</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation">
            </b></span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
    <label for="Visit0WhatIsTheQuoteFor" class="col-md-4 control-label">What Is The Quote For</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <textarea name="data[Visit][0][what_is_the_quote_for]" class="form-control what_is_the_quote_for" cols="30" rows="6" id="Visit0WhatIsTheQuoteFor"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems you need `$(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').show();`

Comment: Or `$(this).closest('.form-group').next().show();` - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vod7fhvs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`what_is_the_quote_for` is parent/ancestor of `visit_status` element, thus your code is not working.

You need traverse up to `form-group` then target its following `form-group`  sibling, then desired operation can be performed.

```
 $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').show()
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.what_is_the_quote_for').closest('.form-group').hide();

  $('.visit_status').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 2) {
      $(this).closest('.form-group').next('.form-group').show()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Visit0VisitStatus" class="col-md-4 control-label">Visit Status</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select name="data[Visit][0][visit_status]" class="visit_status select2-hidden-accessible" id="Visit0VisitStatus" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option value="0" selected>Complete</option>
      <option value="1">In Progress</option>
      <option value="2">First visit complete – quote to be submitted</option>
      <option value="3">First visit complete – parts required</option>
      <option value="4">Further visit required</option>
      <option value="5">Attended – passed back to Diamond</option>
    </select>
    <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--bootstrap select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: auto;">
            <span class="selection">
            <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-Visit0VisitStatus-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-Visit0VisitStatus-container" title="First visit complete – quote to be submitted">First visit complete – quote to be submitted</span>
    <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation">
            </b>
      </span>
    </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
  <label for="Visit0WhatIsTheQuoteFor" class="col-md-4 control-label">What Is The Quote For</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <textarea name="data[Visit][0][what_is_the_quote_for]" class="form-control what_is_the_quote_for" cols="30" rows="6" id="Visit0WhatIsTheQuoteFor"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to show the 4th `.form-group` sibling?

Comment: Can I use `eq` with `next()`? So like `.next('.form-group').eq(3)`?

Comment: @user3574492 `.nextAll('.form-group').eq(3)`